# Lazarus Pascal beep command

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I'm running Lazarus on Windows. I would really like to make the program "Beep".  It appears that you can do so in Pascal using:

```
windows.beep(300,500);
```

But not in Lazarus!  Is there another command that I can use?

Update:

```
sysutils.beep()
```

This works, but I'd really like to set the frequency and duration of sound

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Afaik this is functionality that worked for ages. (Dev Pascal is over ten years old).

What is different is that Lazarus does not automatically add Windows to the uses clause, like Delphi does.

Comment: Are there any simple work arounds? I would really like to play around with frequency and duration for a class that I'm running

Comment: There is no workaround needed. Just add windows to the uses clause and it should work.

Comment: Ah, i see what you mean now, so `use Windows;` fixes it. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

If this function is not declared in Lazarus, you can declare it like:

```
function Beep(dwFreq, dwDuration: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';
```

Comment: Thanks Vitaliy, can you show how it is called?  I've tried Beep(300,300); but it returns an error: unit1.pas(34,3) Error: Wrong number of parameters specified for call to "Beep"

Comment: After you have it declared just call like `beep(300,500);`

Comment: procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

    begin

      Beep(300,300);

    end;

    function Beep(dwFreq, dwDuration: DWORD): BOOL; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll';

code is as above

Comment: it works for me in DEV pascal, just have to change BOOL with boolean:
function Beep(dwFreq, dwDuration: DWORD): boolean; stdcall; external 'kernel32.dll'; //change the first argument and play your favorite song

Comment: HI, I tried that but still getting the same issue. Can you test this in lazarus v1.2.4?

Comment: After you just call it Windows.beep(300,500)

Answer (score 1):

In Lazarus create a new project and add a button. Add windows unit into uses list.
In the button default event put your codes:

```
unit Unit1;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Classes, SysUtils, FileUtil, Forms, Controls, Graphics, Dialogs, StdCtrls,

  windows;  // added by manually

type

  { TForm1 }

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { private declarations }
  public
    { public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.lfm}

{ TForm1 }

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  n,
  freq,dur : integer;

begin
  Randomize;
  for n:=1 to 100 do
    begin
      windows.Beep(random(1000)+n,random(100)+100);
    end;
end;

end.
```